# Распознавание штрихкода с PDF файла

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode

у меня есть толстое приложение на сканере, которое должно сканировать штрихкод с PDF - файла. Штрихкод включает в себя 3 значения [Текстовое значение][пробел][Текстовое значение][пробел][Число]. Нужно чтобы ПО считало, разобрало эти три значения и подставило в 3 выпадающих списка, которые есть в приложении. Как разделить сам штрихкод и подставить его, кто-нибудь может подсказать? Потому что работаю со штрихкодами впервые, да и вообще я чайник. Гугел ни к чему не привел.
Думаю, что проще для разбора было бы заменить пробелы между значениями точкой, потому что в 2 из 3 переменных есть значения, где присутствует пробел

Comment: "Думаю, что проще для разбора было бы заменить пробелы" - как я понимаю pdf вы сами генерите?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Да, сам генерирую штрихкод через fastReport

Comment: Я поясню. Т.е. я понял, что мне нужно распарсить мою строчку используя Split., не совсем понятно как это реализовать в рамках толстого приложения в условиях использования сканера штрихкода

Comment: проверяйте по регулярке